# Python #define equivalent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm developing a Hebrew python library for my toddler, who doesn't speak English yet. So far I've managed to make it work (function names and variables work fine). The problem is with 'if', 'while', 'for', etc.  statements. if this were C++, for ex., I'd use

```
#define if אם
```

are there are any alternatives for #define in Python?

****EDIT*****
For now a quick and dirty solution works for me; instead of running the program I run this code:

```
def RunReady(Path):
    source = open(Path, 'rb')
    program = source.read().decode()
    output = open('curr.py', 'wb')

    program = program.replace('כל_עוד', 'while')
    program = program.replace('עבור', 'for')
    program = program.replace('אם', 'if')
    program = program.replace(' ב ', ' in ')
    program = program.replace('הגדר', 'def')
    program = program.replace('אחרת', 'else')
    program = program.replace('או', 'or')
    program = program.replace('וגם', 'and')
    output.write(program.encode('utf-8'))
    output.close()
    source.close()
    import curr

current_file = 'Sapir_1.py'
RunReady(current_file)
```

Comment: check out https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy

Comment: No, you cannot rename Python syntax; the language simply doesn't support that. You'd have to write your own parser to transform your Hebrew syntax to Python syntax.

Comment: you're teaching Python to a toddler?

Comment: @Scironic Yes I am. She's not really a toddler, being 5 years old..

Comment: @Nikki, Regardless, I know 5 year olds, and if you're successful, that will be impressive!

Comment: @Scironic She's extremely talented and so far, she's doing better than many grown ups I've tried teaching :)

Comment: Congratulations. You've just re-invented the preprocessor. :-)

Answer (score 12):

Python 3 has 33 keywords of which only a few are used by beginners:

```
['False', 'None', 'True', 'and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'case', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'default', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'match', 'nonlocal', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

Given that Python doesn't support renaming keywords it's probably easier to teach a few of these keywords along with teaching programming.

Comment: Phew! So happy I know them all. Anyway I'll suggest an edit because now we also have "match" and "case" and "default".

Answer (score 7):

How about if you add the #define stuff then run the c preprocessor (but not the compiler) which will give you a python source.

Comment: And if `cpp` isn't baroque enough, there is always `m4`. :-) All kidding aside, this is probably the most to-the-point answer.